# Joint.js in Vaadin

Tags: javascript, d3.js, vaadin, jointjs

I am trying to get the joint.js API to work in Vaadin. 
I followed this example of how d3.js is integrated using the AbstractJavaScriptComponent and the Connector.

http://www.rapidpm.org/2013/10/13/using-javascript-libraries-(d3)-in-vaa.html

```
window.connector = function() {

var myElement = this.getElement();
var graph = new joint.dia.Graph;
var paper = new joint.dia.Paper({
    el: $(myElement),
    width: 1500,
    height: 700,
    model: graph
});
var rect = new joint.shapes.basic.Rect({
    position: { x: 100, y: 30 },
    size: { width: 100, height: 30 },
    attrs: { rect: { fill: 'blue' }, text: { text: 'my box', fill: 'white' } }
});

var rect2 = rect.clone();
rect2.translate(300);

var link = new joint.dia.Link({
    source: { id: rect.id },
    target: { id: rect2.id }
});

graph.addCells([rect, rect2, link]);
}
```

In my Component I added the necessary files in the @Javascript annotation:

```
@JavaScript({"dagre.min.js","graphlib.min.js","joint.js","joint.layout.DirectedGraph.js","jquery.min.js","lodash.min.js","d3.js","d3.min.js","connector.js" })

public class Component extends AbstractJavaScriptComponent {
}
```

And then I added the Component to a View. The Problem is I don't really understand, how to access myElement and what it does.I know the connector works fine, since there were no problems using the code from the example with d3.js.If I add myElement like in this code I can't see anything in my view, where I added the Component.

Comment: do you see any errors in the console of the devtools in your browser?  are there error messages if you run your vaadin application with `?debug` at the url?

Comment: I get two errors: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot convert undefined or null to object
    at d.set (backbone-min.js:9)
    at d.constructor (joint.js:5342)
    at new d (backbone-min.js:27)
    at joint.js:9444
    at joint.js:39
    at joint.js:44

Comment: and : Uncaught ReferenceError: joint is not defined
    at :8080/vaadinServlet/APP/PUBLISHED/joint.layout.DirectedGraph.js:20

Comment: I solved these errors. I used the wrong versions of backbone and jquery. Now all errors are gone, but still I can't see anything.